# Lost double quotes after JavaScript assignment

Tags: javascript

I'm having a very strange behaviour of my code (here is the relevant part):

```
var descripcion_concepto = $(xml).find('descripcion_concepto').text();
```

After this instructions if I check the values with Chrome's Developer Tools I get this:

[image]

As you can see, the variable lost the double quotes. Somebody can explain what's happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see lost double quotes, I see a lost `DE  DIAMETRO  EN CONCRE…`?

Comment: Assuming your double-quotes are stored in the XML as `&quot;`, you'll need to use the `.html()` method (instead of `.text()`).

Comment: @Bergi it's because the whole descripction don't fit in the screen for the length of the variable...

Comment: @pete, in the XML the double quotes appeas as double quotes, not as $quot; then maybe the html isn't the solution but I'll try to see the results.